# Do I need an airport transit visa in Dublin when flying from the US to Manchester, England (US citizen)?

Tags: transit-visas, ireland

I'm originally from Nigeria. I have a US passport. Do I need an airport transit visa at Dublin when flying from the US to Manchester in UK? I also have my Nigerian passport.

Answer (score 2):

US citizens do not need a visa to fly into Ireland or the UK as a tourist, in general, so you will not need a visa to transit Dublin.  Just be sure to use your US passport.  (Nigerian citizens very likely need a visa.)

Comment: So I will not need to present my Nigerian passport then?

Comment: @SisterAgatha Indeed, do not present your Nigerian passport unless asked for it, because you'll need a visa if you use it.  If the immigration officer asks if you have other citizenships, of course, answer honestly.  But you must enter as a US citizen to avoid needing a visa.  (There may be some visa-free transit possibilities even with the Nigerian passport, but using the US passport will save you having to investigate this.)

Comment: @JimMacKenzie Indeed, Nigeria is on the very short list of "Appendix 1" countries that require a separate Irish visa to transit Ireland even when holding a UK visa in the British-Irish Visa Scheme. The situation was supposed to be repaired by now, but I think the British and Irish governments have been busy with other matters...